# Userform doesn't appear until I click on the Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am loading an userform through a button click and this userform is not showing up in the front until I click on the workbook. Excel icon keeps blinking and when I click on the worksheet, the blinking stopped and the userform appeared.

what could be the possible reason. It's strange because the same code works for other userforms.

```
FormattingForm.StartUpPosition = 0
FormattingForm.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) 
                      - (0.5 * NewReportEntry.Width)
FormattingForm.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) 
                     - (0.5 * NewReportEntry.Height)    
FormattingForm.Show
```

Comment: Try `FormattingForm.Show vbModal`

Comment: Where is the code? In a class, in a module, in a worksheet or inside the form?

Comment: Try forcing the form to the front using this code:  FormattingForm.ZOrder 0.

Comment: Wondering if since the positioning is based on the excel application and no the user desktop window, the application has to be active to find the positional assignment, what happens just before you go into this code, does the workbook lose user focus?  Try positioning against the user desktop window, center is default I believe.  I have used similar code, and don't come across this problem unless the workbook loses focus.  Maybe an application.visible = true just before the show?

Comment: @Vityata The Code is inside a Module.

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code I have tried setting focus by coding application.visible = true but it didn't help.

Comment: @braX No, it didn't help. Thanks.

Comment: just comment out your 3 positioning statements one time and leave only show, what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends how you call your form. In your case, the cheapest & dirtiest solution would be something like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim FormattingForm As New UserForm1
    FormattingForm.StartUpPosition = 0
    FormattingForm.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width)
    FormattingForm.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height)
    FormattingForm.Show

End Sub
```

`UserForm1` is the name of the Form in the VBEditor:

[image]

If you do not like being dirty and you understand some OOP, try one of this:
https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-the-perfect-userform-in-vba/ 
https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

Or use the old-dirty trick in VBA, writing the code inside the form and calling it there.

Comment: It says, user defined type not defined

Comment: @Sid29 - what & where is this said?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, It says it on New UserForm1 variable declaration

Comment: @Sid29 that would be the name of your form class, i.e. `FormattingForm`. You're not supposed to copy/paste SO answers without trying to understand what's going on...  that said I would recommend to avoid `As New` and split declaration & assignment when writing VBA, especially if you're new at it.

Comment: @Sid29 - Now I got it. The `UesrForm1` is the name of the form. Take a look at it, I have updated the answer. It is the default name for a new form in the VBEditor.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to opening another application. For me, it was MS Word.

When I opened the form after opening Word, Excel would react as you described above. It would blink and I would only see the form after clicking on MS Excel.

```
Set WdDoc = WdApp.Documents.Open(WdDocPathOpen, ReadOnly:=True)
frmLeaseType.Show
```

When I started the form before opening Word, it would act as expected.

```
frmLeaseType.Show
Set WdDoc = WdApp.Documents.Open(WdDocPathOpen, ReadOnly:=True)
```